Window blinds swivel connector
I’m hoping someone might know more about this than I do. I have blinds on almost all my windows in my house. They were here when I moved in, so idk what they’re called, but there’s pieces missing that keep the blinds from opening and closing with the rest. It looks like a little plastic piece with a swivel action so one side attaches to the blind and the other side attaches to a stick that the rest of the blinds are attached to. I need to order replacements of these but I don’t know what they’re called. I have pics but I don't know how to upload them here.
Help!

Use the edit button and find the mountain and sun icon to post pictures.

Are you talking about the wand tilter used to tilt the slats of the blind, where the stick hooks onto and you rotate it to turn the slats up or down?

Thanks @crip659! I meant the wand tilter @huesmann. I actually went to a blind store to ask for help and found out that the parts are called cufflinks! How cute is that?! So I ordered some off amazon and I'm gonna try to fix them myself. Wish me luck!
